# Continuity of a deterministic function generated from a probability function.

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, random-variables

I am working on the proof of a specific proposition on probability theory whose particular case for two variables is presented in the following.

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be different random variables (not necessarily independent) distributed according to continuous probability functions. Let $f(x)$ be a deterministic continuous function on $x \in [a,b].$ Is the function

$$ g(x) = P(X_1 \leq f(x)X_2) $$ continuous on $x \in [a,b]$? $P(\cdot)$ is the probability operator.

If it does, I just need some hints to prove this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the situation where $X_1=cX_2$ has positive probability, $f$ is strictly increasing, and $c$ is in the range of $f$. Then $g$ has a jump at the value of $x$ where $f(x)=c$.

This situation is impossible if $X_1,X_2$ are continuous and independent, for in this case the line $x=cy$ has Lebesgue measure zero, and therefore probability zero (since the joint distribution of $n$ continuous, independent variables is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @ClementC. You're right; let me edit. (I lost track of the $f$.)

Comment: @AlexSilva No, I have not. My assumption only involves $f$. For instance, if $Y$ is uniform on $[1,2]$, then $P(Y \leq x Y)=0$ for $x<1$ and $1$ for $x \geq 1$.

Comment: @AlexSilva Well, I technically have also assumed positivity, but this is not essential; all that is required is that $X_1,X_2$ are equal and not zero with probability $1$. (If they are zero with probability $1$, then your $g$ is identically $1$, which is indeed continuous.)

Comment: If they are equal then you have $P (X \leq X)=1$. You are forgetting about the dependence.

Comment: I changed the problem for the case where $X_1 \neq X_2$. Does it change  anything?

Comment: @AlexSilva Not really. The essential effect I'm describing will occur whenever the line $y=cx$ is assigned positive probability by the joint distribution, $f$ is strictly increasing, and $c$ is in the range of $f$. Note that this is impossible in the continuous, independent case (since a line segment is null with respect to two dimensional Lebesgue measure, it is also null with respect to a continuous probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: Because I changed the question, could you edit your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexSilva Done.