# Counter example of non continuity

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, random-variables

I present in the following a variation of the problem described in [Continuity of a deterministic function generated from a probability function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385525/continuity-of-a-deterministic-function-generated-from-a-probability-function) There,  it has been proved that $g(x)$ is not continuous on $x \in [a,b]$ when there exists a linear relation between the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$.

I wonder if there exists a counter-example where $g(x)$ is not continuous for a non piacewise linear relation between the random variables.

Thanks again!